# How can I do conditional check with parser combinators

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I was trying to write a simple html template engine (for fun), and wanna parse a structure like this

A. normal lines are HTML

B. if a line starts with `$` then view it as a java code line

```
$ if (isSuper) {
    <span>Are you wearing red underwear?</span>
$ }
```

C. if `${}` wraps multiple lines, all code in it should be java code.

D. if a line starts with `$include` then do some trick on the line (call another template)

```
$include anotherTemplate(id, name)
```

this will create a new instance of `anotherTemplate`, and call it's `render()` method

E. and there would be more "commands" other than `$include`, such as `$def`, `$val`.

How can I express this in parser combinators? In effect it is a conditional fork

for 1. and 2., I got something like this:

```
'$' ~> ( '{' ~> upto('}') <~ '}' |  not('{') <~ newline )
```

where `upto` is borrowed from Scalate Scamel parser (which I just start to read and can't quite understand)

I used `not('{')` to distinguish `$....` code line with `${...}` block. But this is cumbersome, and won't extend to other "commands"

So How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Your use of `not` is redundant. The `|` method implements *ordered* choice; the second thing is tried only if the first has failed. This should do the trick:

```
def directive: Parser[Directive] =
  ( '$' ~>
    ( '{' ~> javaStuff <~ '}'
    | "include" ~> includeDirective
    | "def"     ~> defDirective
    | "val"     ~> valDirective
    | javaDirective
    )
  | htmlDirective
  )

def templateFile: Parser[List[Directive]] = (directive <~ '\n').*
```

For faster parsing and better error messages, you should "commit" your parsers as often as possible. I think this is what you were trying to get at when you used `not('{')`.

Right now, if the above parser sees a `'$'` followed by a `'{'` and then *doesn't* see `javaStuff`, it'll backtrack and consider each of the four remaining `'$'`-alternatives in order (`include`, `def`, `val`, and finally `javaDirective`), and then backtrack to before `'$'` to try `htmlDirective`, before failing with a baffling error message. But if we see a `'{'`, we know that none of the other alternatives could possibly succeed, so why should we check them? Likewise, a line that starts with `'$'` can never be an `htmlDirective`.

We want things like `'{'` to be points of no backtrack; if the after-`'{'` parser fails and wants to backtrack, we should stop it in its tracks and propagate the backtrack-causing failure directly to the user as an error.

The way to do this is with `commit`. This function/combinator, when applied to a parser `p`, looks at the `ParseResult` coming out of `p` and changes it to an `Error` (the give-up-entirely signal) if it was originally a `Failure` (the backtrack signal), leaving it unchanged otherwise. With appropriate use of `commit`, the `directive` parser becomes:

```
def directive: Parser[Directive] =
  ( '$' ~> commit( '{' ~> commit(javaStuff <~ '}')
                 | "include" ~> commit(includeDirective)
                 | "def"     ~> commit(defDirective)
                 | "val"     ~> commit(valDirective
                 | javaDirective
                 )
  | htmlDirective
  )
```

When I first learned to use the parsing library, I found it really helpful to look at [the source code for `Parsers`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala#L1); it makes some of this stuff a bit more clear.

(Some other tips: The purpose of `append` and `ParseResult#append` is to decide which failure from a sequence of parse-alternatives should be propagated to the user. Just ignore those for now. Also, I wouldn't worry too much about `>>`/`flatMap`/`into` until you've gotten some more practice; when it's time, read [Daniel Sobral's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7985029/784326). Finally, I've never had to use `|||`, and you probably won't either. Happy parsing!)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Thanks! Do you have any suggestions for improving it?